# Where is the source of the prohibition of listening to Kol Isha?

Tags: halacha

It is well known that listening to a women sing is forbidden. Where is the source to the Prohibition?

Comment: For most people there is no such prohibition AFAIK.

Comment: #DoubleAA Why not?

Comment: Most people are female.